# Strange behaviour of PHPUnit + Xdebug + PhpStorm

Tags: php, shell, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm + Xdebug + PHPUnit in shell on Debian.
Works fine but there is a strange behaviour, mostly boring.

When I run `phpunit` command in shell, the first break that PhpStorm show me is in `/usr/local/bin/phpunit` in the line where it check the php version...

But Obviously I don't have put any breakpoint in that file.

```
if (version_compare('5.6.0', PHP_VERSION, '>')) {
fwrite(
    STDERR,
    'This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of PHP is highly recommended.' . PHP_EOL
);

die(1);
}
```

In addition, the file is very large so it remains blocked several seconds before you can go ahead.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Uncheck `Run | Break at first line in PHP scripts`. But most likely it will not help -- then you have to check settings in `Setting/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug` -- look at `Force break at the first line...` options  -- most likely 2nd one is doing this.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks. I have unchecked "Force break at the first line when a script is outside the project" and now works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, it worked! Such an annoying option.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that `Run | Break at first line in PHP scripts` is un-checked.

But most likely it will not help here. If so:

1. `Setting/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug`
2. Uncheck the `Force break at the first line when a script is outside the project` option -- based on your description this one is responsible for this behaviour.